# Output-sensitive fast enumeration of all maximal subsets of non-overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm

So given a set of intervals, finding a subset of non-overlapping intervals that has the maximal number of intervals can be done in linear time after sorting the intervals by their right end-points. However, what if we want to output ALL solution subsets with a maximal number of non-overlapping intervals? The running time should be output-sensitive, because for n intervals the number of optimal solutions could be exponential, e.g. as high as O(sqrt(n)^sqrt(n)). So if there are S optimal solutions, can they be enumerated in time linearly proportional to the size of S (perhaps with polynomial dependence on n as well)?

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I was familiar with the greedy algorithm for finding a maximal non-overlapping set, but not the dynamic programming algorithm. I had a feeling there was a fairly easy answer though like the posted answer by tmpyklebu. When I have a feeling an answer is "easy" (e.g. just requiring some basic background) I put the question here, because I feel like it's a waste of cs.stackexchange.com 's time. Other people post algorithm interview questions here. I see my post the same way. Maybe I need to understand the intent of the different sites better, but there is an algorithms tag here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Also appropriate here; it's a practical, answerable programming problem.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that it *had* to be on cs, it was a question. To be honest the entire question is out of my league, but it didn't seem like you had a "practical" programming problem. But you're right, algorithm questions are on-topic on both sites. I see now that you have accepted the answer given, my comment was only about how to increase your chance of getting usable answers, but that is all water under the bridge now :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yeah, there's a weird subset of SO users who think the site's exclusively about debugging poorly-written PHP code or something.  Didn't mean to accuse you of being one of those; I just wanted to preemptively stem the tide of folks hitting "close" because there's no broken PHP code in the question.

Comment: Sometimes I am one of those, depends on the question :P But this was not one of those times, as I said, the question is a bit out of my league. For all I knew, user2566092 didn't know about CS.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yeah, it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the standard dynamic programming algorithm for largest independent set in an interval graph.  This tells you what the maximum number is.  It is straightforward to modify this algorithm to track the number of ways to get said maximum number.

For every interval I, compile a list of all of the later intervals that do not overlap I from which you can form an independent set of maximum size.

Now run a straightforward recursive enumeration of all independent sets using the information compiled in the last paragraph.

If the size of the maximum independent set is h, this will take O(hS + n^2) time; the n^2 is for the DP and the hS is for the recursion and output.